# User defined data schemas for applications

Tags: database, database-design, dsl

I want to write an application that allows users to define their own data base schemas. The user provides a definition  using a DSL (biological experiments) and based on this, an oop/entity relation model is generated. The backend should be an RDBMS such as Postgres.

What is the best way to do this?

I can see two possible ways off the top of my head:

1. Map types to SQL tables just like you would when writing a Django or Hibernate based application. Objects then map to table rows.
2. Describe the types in an "type" table and objects in another table.

What do people generally do here? For 1., permission managent etc. could be handed to the rdbms. However how would one be able to track changes here and allow rollbacks?

Can anyone point me towards best practice?

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? You write you want an RDBMS, an oop/entity relation model, permission management, track changes, allow rollbacks. But you hardly hinted at the purpose of what you are creating.

Comment: Is the user providing a DSL a fixed requirement - could it for example be some XML or JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice depends much on your application's specific needs.  For example, Option 1 is appropriate if you are writing an application generator with technically savvy and trustworthy users.  This, for example, is the approach taken by PeopleSoft Application Designer.  Tracking changes and allowing rollbacks is tricky, since you can't roll back something like a dropped column.  You could write some complicated arrangement with a custom audit table to track what was done, and logic to make it reversible.  But you would still lose data with that dropped column.  If storage is no concern, you could make a backup copy of the table with each change, and the rollback would simply restore that backup.  But then you would risk losing data that had been added to the table between the change and the rollback.

On the other hand, if what you are creating is more like a survey generator, then I have done something a little like option 2.  Keep a metadata table that shows what a "record" is.  The record itself is actually stored in two tables - parent and child.  The parent table identifies the record, but all the fields are stored in the child table, as key-value pairs.  You have complete flexibility to store whatever you want, and you never have to muck with dynamically changing the database schema.  You can even preserve historical versions of the metadata, so that you can always reference historical records without losing data.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options, actually way more then you offer.

**Don't do Option 1** Dynamically creating tables/schemas is really weird, except when you are writing a generic database client, like TOAD, or a RAD tool. It doesn't sound like this is what you want to build, but if just use one of the existing ones. Of course you could create all the classes, mapping information and scripts dynamically, but for what purpose? You have to use them using reflection anyway since they don't exist when you write your program.

**Don't use an RDBMS** The idea behind an RDBMS is that it has a more or less fixed schema. If this doesn't fit your needs, don't do it. Use something more dynamic. A NoSql database like MongoDb might fit your needs. If rollback is really important, you could use a git repository as backend.

**Maybe it's a datawarehouse?** You are talking about "experiments". So if you have to store measurements, this might be just that: measurements and they would a have a type and an experiment they belong to ... a little like Option 2. To learn more about this, you might want to look up "star schemas"